# Which question sounds more natural?

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage, sentence-structure

I'm trying to write a question that would sound natural to native speakers. Could you help me?

1. What are you going to surprise me with?
2. What will you surprise me with?
3. How will you surprise me?
4. How are you going to surprise me?

I like the first question better but I'm not sure if they say it this way or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of "will" or "going to" is just a matter of style, there is no significant difference in meaning. If you prefer "going to" for this, then use it.

The choice of "With what" or "How" asks for different things.  Ask "What are you going to surprise me with" to get an answer that is a noun "...With abox of chocolates".  Ask "How" for description of the method: "...By taking you out for dinner." (aside, Happy Valentines day!)

The question is a bit pointless either way!  If the person answers, then it won't be a surprise anymore... will it?

Comment: The answer conveys the surprise, surely?